# GPU shader processors count

Tags: c++, wmi, shader, gpu

I need to determine the number of shader processors, i looked up the WMI Win32_VideoController class, but there's no information about shaders. Is there anyway i can find a count of the shader processosrs?

Comment: Use Direct3D or OpenGL functions

Comment: no way i can get it just using winapi?

Comment: @Vanya: Those are just as much part of the WinAPI as WMI is.

Comment: can you please help me? i want to call those api from pure c, i guess i need the com interface, is there any examples?

Comment: seems that  `ID3D11Device::CreateQuery` is what i need

Comment: ok i looked up the  `ID3D11Device::CreateQuery` but there's no info about hardware avaliable via this method

Comment: I found the `wglGetGPUInfoAMD` function in the OpenGL specification, but there's no way according to documentation, that i can get the number of processors in GPU https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/wgl_gpu_association.txt as described here

Comment: So i guess opengl doesn't fit me, i'am surprised that susch simple task is so hard to implement....